# Is there a way to get the name of Class#1 when the method of an instance of Class#2 is called from a method within Class#1?

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a class (e.g., `ErrorWarningLog`) which is used for logging error and warning messages for a specific application. I instantiate this class in the main method, and it is passed around to various other classes and methods to store the accumulated error and warning messages as a list of strings.

Within the logging class I have two methods: `AddError(string...)` and `AddWarning(string...)`.

When testing e.g., Application1, I invoke one of its methods, application1_method1() to test a specific feature, and if it fails, I add an error or warning message, `ErrorWarningLog.AddError("my error...")`.

```
public class ErrorWarningLog
{
    List<string> errorList
    List<string> warningList
    public void AddError(string error) {...}
    public void AddWarning(string warning) {...}
}


public class Application1
{
    public void application1_method1(ErrorWarningLog ewl)
    {
        ...
        ...
        ewl.AddError("my error")
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to tag each of these Error and Warning messages with the class whose method found an error, e.g., so error would look like "Application1 - my error...".

I would like a solution that adds this to the `AddError()` or `AddWarning()` method themselves, rather than adding it when calling these methods.

I don't know if it is possible. Perhaps via reflection?

I currently add the class name manually on each call to method `AddError` or `AddWarning`, but would like to remove this step.

Comment: Consider using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, which does this automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to add the type, either via a string or via a generic type parameter.

Comment: There's only the [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information) attribute, an equivalent for the class name doesn't exist. However, you could add another parameter to your method and call it like this: `AddWarning("foo", typeof(this).Name);`

Comment: I suppose the class name could be a parameter of the method, or you could try passing a reference to the instance of the class.

Comment: Don't use `string` to hold errors, make your own type `Error` with properties to store various info.

Comment: You could use [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-8.0) on a string argument of your method, but it gives you the filename where the caller member resides, and not the class name. 

You could also retrieve the stack trace using `System.Diagnostic` with something like this `new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;`, but for performance reason I don't think it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePathAttribute`.

```cs
public void AddError(string error, [CallerFilePath] string source = "")
{
    string fullMessage = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source)} - {error}";
    ...
}
```

Note that the second parameter is optional. Don't specify it at the call site!

It is important to store the class `Application1` in its own file `Application1.cs` (and not say as a nested class) for this to work.

My test setup:

```
// File Application1.cs
public class Application1
{
    public void application1_method1(ErrorWarningLog ewl)
    {
        ewl.AddError("my error");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ErrorWarningLog
{
    public void AddError(string error, [CallerFilePath] string source = "")
    {
        string fullMessage = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source)} - {error}";

        Console.WriteLine(fullMessage);
    }
}
```

The test:

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    var app = new Application1();
    app.application1_method1(new ErrorWarningLog());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

prints:

```
Application1 - my error
```

Comment: My comment was on your first version and doesn't apply anymore, anyway